# How to Enable/Disable Command Menu Button Conditionally

Tags: macos, swiftui, menu

I try to enable/disable Command Menu buttons of the App based on the DetailView appeared or not (view appeared = button enabled).
For that I try to use `@EnvironmentalObject` to receive the current condition via an `ViewState` class using it to enable/disable the button:

```
@main
 struct MyApp: App {
  ...
  
  // access viewState via Environmental Object
  @EnvironmentObject var viewState: ViewState

  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
    ...
    }

    .commands {
        
      // changing "File" menu list
      CommandGroup(after: CommandGroupPlacement.undoRedo) {
        
        Button("Listeneintrag bearbeiten") {
            // do stuff
        }.disabled(!viewState.itemSelected)  // <-- ERROR OCCURING
      }
    }
 }
}
```

`ViewState` is defined as `ObservableObject` holding the variables

```
class ViewState : ObservableObject {

  @Published var userSelected = false
  @Published var itemSelected = false
}
```

in my DetailsView the view appearances shall set the state ov the ObservableObject vars:

```
struct DetailsView: View {
 ...
 @StateObject var viewState = ViewState()

 var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
  ...
 }
 .onAppear {
    viewState.userSelected = true
 }
 .onDisappear {
    viewState.userSelected = false
 }
}
```

The Error message is: `Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type ViewState found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for ViewState may be missing as an ancestor of this view.`

My approach might be completely wrong but I used it to share information from `App` to the views successfully. I did not find any information on how to pass data/information from views to the (main) app struct.
Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is telling you that in your App, there is no `viewState` model.
This is because you have to declare your `viewState` (the single source of truth) in the parent of your view hierarchy,
to be passed down to other views.
And App is the top most in the view hierarchy. So you have your logic back to front.

Therefore, try this approach where you declare `@StateObject var viewState = ViewState()` in your App, and pass this model to your other views. This gives you a two way `communication` between the App and the other views, **and vice versa**.

Example code:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject var viewState = ViewState()  // <--- here
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(viewState) // <--- here
        }
        .commands {
            CommandGroup(after: CommandGroupPlacement.undoRedo) {
                Button("Listeneintrag bearbeiten") {
                    // ...
                }.disabled(!viewState.itemSelected)
            }
        }
    }
}

class ViewState : ObservableObject {
  @Published var userSelected = false
  @Published var itemSelected = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        // ...
        DetailsView()
    }
}

struct DetailsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewState: ViewState  // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("DetailsView")
            Button("Enable/Disable Listeneintrag bearbeiten button") { // <-- for testing
                viewState.itemSelected.toggle()
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewState.userSelected = true
        }
        .onDisappear {
            viewState.userSelected = false
        }
    }
}
```

Have a look at this  **official** link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app:  [Monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app). Note that if you are targeting iOS17, see [Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app).